# Google apps retrieve user info

Tags: xml, api, schema, config

I have created a software that connects to google apps email and allows me to create a signature for specified users with their info. In google apps domain management is no possibility to edit more "advanced" fields like company address, fax, emails, title, nickname etc.. so i used Flash Panel which offer me this possibility. But for this i need the fields api schema to add it in my config. I have managed to make it work for some fields like: Name, Company name, email address, mobile phone, title, department, manager, fax number by adding the following in my config file:

```
<string>cn=Name.FullName</string>
<string>company=Organizations[Rel:http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work].Name</string>
<string>mail=PrimaryEmail.Address</string>
<string>mobile=Phonenumbers[Rel:http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#mobile].Value</string>
<string>title=Organizations[Rel:http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work].Title</string><string>department=Organizations[Rel:http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work].Department</string>
<string>managerGA=ContactEntry.Relations[Rel:manager].Value</string>
<string>facsimiletelephonenumber=Phonenumbers[Rel:http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work_fax].Value</string>
```

I have searched through google documentation but i didn't managed to find the correct api schema format for some fields like: country, city, pobox, street, nickname, photo, website, URL, Notes, Organization Unit, Aka, and any others. Can someone help me with the correct ones or where/how can i find them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope here you can find something that helps you: 
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/